# How to do TLS handshake in one process and handle the rest of connection in another process?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ssl, openssl

I've been trying to implement a TLS server.
Due to some requirements, I need to accept the TLS handshake on one process and do the symmetric crypto operation (and the rest of the TLS connection) on another process (these process run on different devices).
Currently, I am thinking about 2 possible solutions:

1. Get the key, iv and some others information from SSL context - pass
   them into the second process along with the socket fd - do enc/dec
   and send/recv via the socket connection. The normal encryption/
   decryption part is not a big problem but the other stuffs (error
   checking, alert, renegotiation...) will be a nightmare.
2. Somehow pass the whole SSL context (the SSL struct) to the second
   process and reuse it. I found several questions years ago about this
   approach but none of them have a good answer.

So is there any ways to do the second approach with OpenSSL (someone suggest using TLSe project but I just want to stick with original OpenSSL)?
If anyone's solved this problem, is there any better solution for it?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why? A lot of the heavy crypto takes place in the handshake. You would be better off doing the entire exchange including the TLS handshake in the child process.

Comment: I'm trying to do the handshake and symmetric crypto on 2 devices, each have specific hardware accelerator.

Comment: *I'm trying to do the handshake and symmetric crypto on 2 devices* "Another device"?  As in another computer entirely, with another instance of an OS running?  To do that, you'd have to *start* by properly transferring the entire state of the TCP connection, then figure out how to get the packets from the remote end of the connection to go where you want.

Comment: Yup, it's another tricky part. Currently, I'm trying to find a way to transparently transfer the control of socket connection to the second machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform TLS handshake in one process,then fork a new process,accepted socket that was involved in TLS handshake will be shared with child process using that you can do the send()/recv() part in child process

If the two processes are not related, I am afraid there is no way you can do TLS handshake on one process/device and reuse it on another process/device over a diffrent socket

TLS is for creating secure tunnel between 2 endpoints, both end points authnticate each other(for server to authenticate client is optional), what you are trying is not possible, each new connection must undergo new handshake

SSL sessions can be reused for the endpoints that already undergone handshake between them, its not applicable here when you want to connect to entirely new entity

Comment: Yep, it will be a lot easier if the second process is forked after accepting client connection.
Unfortunately, the second process is created before that.

Comment: Thats even better, as @EJP points out you can do handshake in the child process as they re heavy

Comment: Actually, what I'm trying to do is performing handshake on a device, and then handling the rest of the connection on another device. So, the 1st and 2nd process here is not parent and child.

Comment: I made this work locally, by extracting some information from the ssl context, sending them to the new process, and creating a new ssl struct with those information. Then I can use the new ssl struct to send and receive data IF I use the same socket connection (still have a lot of potential problems here since in some case, the new ssl struct might require others information from old ssl struct). But at least the normal case work. Now the problem is how to transfer socket connection from machine to machine. Do you have any idea about this?